# Why is this jquery changing the value of my date?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

```
    alert($('#CategoryEffDate').val());
    $('#CategoryEffDate').datepicker();
    $('#CategoryEndDate').datepicker();
    $('#CategoryEffDate').datepicker('option', { minDate: formatDate('19000101'), maxDate: formatDate('20030101') });
    $('#CategoryEndDate').datepicker('option', { minDate: formatDate('99991231'), maxDate: formatDate('99991231') });
    alert($('#CategoryEffDate').val());
```

What do I have wrong here?  I am trying to set min date and max date for my date pickers, but it keeps changing the values to the max dates in the date picker.

My alert before displays 06/01/2014, the one after displays 01/01/2003

Comment: you set the max date to 20030101, which comes before 20140601, so the datepicker corrects the date to the closest date between the min and max (which in this case is the max date.)

Comment: That works!!  I wish I would have noticed that.  Sometimes you miss the simple things.

Comment: @KevinB Please ad it as an answer so that the question will be *actually* answered...

Answer (score 0):

you set the max date to `20030101` which comes before `20140601`, so the datepicker corrects the date to the closest date between the min and max (which in this case is the max date.)